# Angular 5 Local Storage Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, karma-jasmine

I am getting an error '**SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0**'  in Jasmin Karma Angular testing. I recoginzed that this error is due to local storage JSON parsing. Also I am getting '**ERROR in src/app/projects/project-details/project-details.component.spec.ts(77,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'm'.**' in the console.

```js
this.RowSelected = JSON.parse(localStorage['ProjectArray']);
```

I tried  changing my component code to the below, JSON U Token seems to gone but a new error seems to throw like 'Typerror: cannot read property 'projectId' as null'. Can someone help me in mocking local storage for my app. Thanks.

```js
this.RowSelected = JSON.parse(localStorage['ProjectArray'] || null);
```

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectDetailsComponent } from './project-details.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { ProjectSearchService } from '../../core/project-services/project-search.service';
import { StoreDataService } from '../../core/project-services/store-data.service';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('ProjectDetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: ProjectDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProjectDetailsComponent>;

  
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule, BsDatepickerModule, HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([]) ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
      declarations: [ ProjectDetailsComponent ],
      providers: [StoreDataService, ProjectSearchService]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProjectDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    function storageMock() {
    var storage = {};
      return {
      setItem: function(key, value) {
        storage[key] = value || '';
      },
      getItem: function(key) {
        return key in storage ? storage[key] : null;
      },
      removeItem: function(key) {
        delete storage[key];
      },
      get length() {
        return Object.keys(storage).length;
      },
      key: function(i) {
        var keys = Object.keys(storage);
        return keys[i] || null;
      }
    };
  }
    let mockConfig = JSON.stringify({
            projectId: "015104072",
            csj: "015104072",
            ccsj: "015104072",
            controlSection: "015104",
            projectType: "Construction",
            projectSubtype: "Roadway",
            district: "Austin",
            county: "Williamson",
            assignedTo: null,
            projectStatus: "Active",
            projectStage: "Ready to Let",
            projectClassification: "Intersection & Operational Imprv",
            letScheduleFiscalYear: "2018",
            dateCreated: "2018-07-20",
            highway: "US 183"
  });
  //Set storage
 let m =  storageMock();
 m.setItem('ProjectArray', mockConfig);
  
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', { value: m });
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    component.RowSelected = JSON.parse(m.getItem('ProjectArray'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem is that the value is undefined, so you need to handle that case in your code. Otherwise, as soon as this is run in a browser where the values are set, I imagine you'll see the same errors?

Comment: Forget to attach how I am calling my local storage:      ngOnInit() { this.RowSelected = JSON.parse(localStorage['ProjectArray']); }

Comment: did you figure out how to do it? @ManojCMRReddy Even I am facing the same issue